# How to use regular expressions with helm-projectile-grep?

Tags: regular-expressions, helm-projectile, helm-grep

I would like to find all strings in files matching the pattern `foo_*_bar`. I know that one can use `\s` to match empty characters. What's the pattern for zero or more characters? Could not find it by searching the web.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, I discovered that the following works `foo_[[:alnum:]]*_bar`. `[[:alnum:]]` matches alphanumeric characters and `*` matches the preceding item zero or more times, i.e. without `*` the string `foo__bar` does not match the pattern.